# "Hit the ball twice" in cricket, so does that means that batsman can hit the ball twice?

Tags: rules, cricket, terminology

As per the name its like Hit the ball twice, so does that means a batsman can hit the ball twice, I mean the same delivery can b played twice?

Comment: Leg before wicket, so does that mean you can put your leg out to stop the ball hitting the stumps? No, of course not. You're leaving out the first and all-important word from the phrase. "Out".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Hitting the ball twice intentionally is essentially an illegal action which may result in the batsman being given out *Hit the ball twice* under [Law 34.1](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-34-hit-the-ball-twice/):

> The striker is out Hit the ball twice if, while the ball is in play, it strikes any part of his person or is struck by his bat and, before the ball has been touched by a fielder, he wilfully strikes it again with his bat or person [...].

The only instance where the batsman may strike it again legally is  when he does so solely to protect his wicket, as described by Law 34.3:

> Solely in order to guard his wicket and before the ball has been touched by a fielder, the striker may lawfully strike the ball a second or subsequent time with his bat [...].

No runs are scored by the batsman when the ball has been hit twice.

Comment: I'm glad you have included the word "intentionally" here. I believe you will find that often a batting stroke does actually involve the ball contacting the bat more than once - especially with pull shots to leg. A lot of the time it goes unnoticed - but occasionally you can hear two separate knocks. As far as I know there is nothing illegal in that. It is an altogether different thing to play a second stroke at the ball.